Resolution and Brightness Ubuntu 20.04
I recently installed Ubuntu 20.04 in dual boot with Windows 11 on MSI Vector 16 HX A13 with NVIDIA RTX 4080. Unfortunately there are some problems that, trying some solutions proposed online, I was unable to solve. These are:

fractional scale that does not work, in fact setting it to 125% always and only sets me to 200%.
Inability to adjust the screen brightness from either a key combination or from settings (do not even compare the brightness setting). I tried to edit the /etc/default/grub file and change GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash" to GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_backlight=none", but it did not work.


Please use a recent version of Ubuntu like 24.04. It would have much better out-of-the-box support for recent hardware

issues like this can sometimes be resolved by going to Settings > Accessibility > Seeing and setting High Contrast on.

@ArchismanPanigrahi I need to use 20.04 for ROS1

Try the following: Use Ubuntu 24.04 for all computing, and run 20.04 in Virtualbox for ROS. Your computer is very recent. It will not be well-supported by 20.04

@Il Graham it doesn't work
